# Using Org-Mode to view results from python script

Tags: org-mode

How can I use org-mode to run python scripts ?  Would it be possible to see the results from running commands interactively ?

Comment: See [Working with source code](https://orgmode.org/manual/Working-with-Source-Code.html) in the Org mode manual. On running commands interactively, while you *could* run code blocks with a `:session` header argument to simulate an interactive session, it would be simpler to run a python session in an inferior Python process: less typing that way. Try `M-x run-python` to get such a session - if you encounter problems, do `C-h f run-python` to see what settings you need.

Answer (score 1):

To run a python script from emacs in org-mode, put the script in a code block and evaluate it using `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c`.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output
print("Hello, world!")
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: Hello, world!
```

For an interactive session from emacs, do `M-x run-python`.

[image]

[image]